# How to calculate skewness, kurtosis and quartiles with zonal statistics?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I would like to calculate the skewness, kurtosis and quartiles for the elevation of a raster and for a point feature class inside the area of some polygons. I used the zonal statistic tool in ArcGis but with this tool I can just calculate the mean, stddev, max, min. Hope someone can help me? I read that there is a tool in Grass Gis to calculate skewness etc. but I hope I can do it in ArcGIS so i don't have to switch between the programms all the time